# combobox onchange event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

Hi I use this code in order to create a combobox. The problem is that I can't use the onchange event. I tried to complete the function $( ".prodottoAutocomplete" ).combobox(); inserting the change event but I didn't obtain nothing and the event doesn't start.
Thanks

```
<script>
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
_create: function() {
this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
  .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
  .insertAfter( this.element );

   this.element.hide();
   this._createAutocomplete();
   this._createShowAllButton();
},
_createAutocomplete: function() {
var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
  value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
this.input = $( "<input>" )
  .appendTo( this.wrapper )
  .val( value )
  .attr( "title", "" )
  .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
  .autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
  })
  .tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
this._on( this.input, {
  autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    this._trigger( "select", event, {
      item: ui.item.option
    });
  },
  autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
  });
},
_createShowAllButton: function() {
var input = this.input,
  wasOpen = false;
$( "<a>" )
  .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
  .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
  .tooltip()
  .appendTo( this.wrapper )
  .button({
    icons: {
      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
    },
    text: false
  })
  .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
  .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
  .mousedown(function() {
    wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
  })
  .click(function() {
    input.focus();
    // Close if already visible
    if ( wasOpen ) {
      return;
    }
    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
  });
},
_source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
    return {
      label: text,
      value: text,
      option: this
    };
 }) );
},
_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
// Selected an item, nothing to do
if ( ui.item ) {
  return;
}
// Search for a match (case-insensitive)
var value = this.input.val(),
  valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
  valid = false;
this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
  if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
    this.selected = valid = true;
    return false;
  }
});
// Found a match, nothing to do
if ( valid ) {
  return;
}
// Remove invalid value
this.input
  .val( "" )
  .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
  .tooltip( "open" );
this.element.val( "" );
this._delay(function() {
  this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
}, 2500 );
this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
},
_destroy: function() {
  this.wrapper.remove();
  this.element.show();
}
});
})( jQuery );
$(function() {
    $( ".prodottoAutocomplete" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
       $( ".prodottoAutocomplete" ).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to use the onchange event of the select element.
this is the demo
https://jsfiddle.net/b2z7kw5u/1/

Comment: Suggest you create a sandbox demo and explain which element you are talking about

Comment: sorry. Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/b2z7kw5u/1/
I would like to set the on change event

Comment: change on which element? The original select? Please provide full description of the problem in the question